# popup html page not returning value?

Tags: javascript, html

Please can anyone help me? The following javascript code is working in IE9 & above version and firefox also but lower version of IE(8,7) does not supporting.

```
function SetName() {
    var a = sessionStorage.getItem("sent");
    var b = window.opener.document.getElementById("tclass").value;
    var c = window.opener.document.getElementById("ttype").value;
    var noPMMCode = window.opener.document.getElementById("noPMMCode").value;
    var noLTMMCode = window.opener.document.getElementById("noLTMMCode").value;
    var noLEMMCode = window.opener.document.getElementById("noLEMMCode").value;
    var noSTMMCode = window.opener.document.getElementById("noSTMMCode").value;
    if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed && b == "Material" && c == "PT" && noPMMCode != null) {
        var txtName = window.opener.document.getElementById("PMMC" + a);
        txtName.value = document.getElementById("ddlNames").value;
    } else if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed && b == "Material" && c == "LT-NORMAL" && noLTMMCode != null) {
        var txtName = window.opener.document.getElementById("LTMMC" + a);
        txtName.value = document.getElementById("ddlNames").value;
    } else if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed && b == "Material" && c == "LT-EMPANEL" && noLEMMCode != null) {
        var txtName = window.opener.document.getElementById("LEMMC" + a);
        txtName.value = document.getElementById("ddlNames").value;
    } else if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed && b == "Material" && c == "ST" && noSTMMCode != null) {
        var txtName = window.opener.document.getElementById("STMMC" + a);
        txtName.value = document.getElementById("ddlNames").value;
    }
    window.close();
}
```

Advance Thanks..

Comment: May be due to disable of java script in IE8. Try to check whether java script enabled in IE8 or not.

Comment: IIRC `window.opener` in IE is affected by security zones settings, may be impacting your testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.opener won't work in IE under default security level.

An option is to use location.href to redirect the child window to a page in the domain same as the parent window and then use window.opener

Comment: do you have any idea about how to redirect to a new page from popup page?

Comment: In IE , pass this parameter "copyhistory=no" in Window.open parameters          Eg: window.open('','Name','height=320','width=428','resizable=no','location=no', 'directories=no',    
     'status=no','copyhistory=no');